# Why the QT QNetworkAccessManager example dont works in my Program ?

Tags: c++, json, eclipse, qt, networking

i would write a programm that becomes data from a Url. When i open this Url with firefox, i became a .json data. The same i would make with my qt project: Open a url, that returns the same .json data. I must use the QNetworkAccessManager, right ? 
But when i use the example from the qt project site, it make a syntax error. I have make all includes. 
This is the code from the example , i use the same in my project.:

```
QNetworkRequest request;
QNetworkAccessManager *manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
connect(manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),
        this, SLOT(replyFinished(QNetworkReply*)));

QNetworkReply *reply = manager->get(request);
manager->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl("http://qt.nokia.com")));
request.setUrl(QUrl("http://qt.nokia.com"));
```

I know that this dont returns me my .json data, but at first i will can opened a url.
Why my program make a syntax error. When i delete this, my program works. ( Without parsing, but it views and the buttoncklicks works. 
Thank you

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: A Syntax error, it write this code red. :
undefined reference to `QNetworkAccessManager::get(QNetworkRequest const&)' the same error for each  .. 
undefined reference to `QNetworkAccessManager::get(QNetworkRequest const&)' etc.

Comment: Add network module to project file, for qmake projects it is just a `QT += network`

Answer (score 0):

It seams you got error message something like this "invalid use of 'this' in non-member function" right?
When you use *this pointer it should point to some object.

You have to do something like here:

```
class Request : public QObject {
     Q_OBJECT
public:
     Request(QObject *parent=0);
     ~Request();

public slots:
     void replyFinished(QNetworkReply *))
private:
     QNetworkAccessManager *m_manager;
}
```

Then in  request.cpp you can do it like here:

```
Request::Request(QObject *parent): QObject(parent) {
    m_manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
    QObject::connect(m_manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),
                     this, SLOT(replyFinished(QNetworkReply *)));
}

Request::~Request() {
    delete m_manager;
}

void Request::replyFinished(QNetworkReply *reply) {
    //do_something
}
```

Then you can use it like  here:

```
Request *handle = new Request():
handle->do_some_methods();
//...etc
```

Comment: ouch, you even can fine more here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25433706/qt-console-app-using-qnetworkaccessmanager